# Excel Force Calculation

Tags: validation, excel, excel-formula, volatile, vba

I have a cell that is evaluated by

`=IF(OR(J41="",J40=""),"",(1-($J$41/$J$40)))`

computing the percent error between two cells that the user inputs.  Additionally,  I have an IFC on a seperate sheet that is validating this cell, among other cells, and setting it to a certain color with a warning if the percent error value is above/below a certain number.  The problem is that the cell does not show the warning unless I click on it and hit enter (or F2 + Enter), which calculates the cell and populates the value at that time.  Is there a way to Force the calculation to occur in that cell when the user inputs values into J41 and J40, thus  populating the warning immediately?  I have checked multiple threads on this, some say use the Application.Volatile statement, but I am not too sure if that will work..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, It is just a interface table with VBA running in the background I've created that references all of the cells in my form and sets certain restrictions/validations on them, and also picks up values in the form that then export to a 1-row table to be inserted into a DB.  It is just an interface that can be set to validate data.

Comment: If you're using code to do all this, it would be an idea to show it. ;)

Comment: Agree with @Rory - your description is lacking enough detail to determine exactly how your validation is being triggered. That formula you show should update automatically.

Comment: `Application.Volatile True` works if you are using a UDF, are you? See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: No not a UDF, it is calculated in the cell itself.  All I want this to do is validate the calculation in the cell with the formula in it.  The cell does validation does not work until I click on it and hit enter again.  How is this not enough detail? When a cell has a formula in it, it displays the result as opposed to putting the value of the result into that cell.  I want the value of the result in the cell so that the data validation immediately picks it up and says if it is a correct number or not... Make sense?

Comment: Method [`Application.Calculate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually calculating a range is as simple as using `Range.Calculate`.
To run code when a value is changed in a certain range, use `Worksheet_Change`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngTrigger As Range: Set rngTrigger = Range("D5")
    Dim rngTarget As Range: Set rngTarget = Range("E5")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngTrigger) Is Nothing Then _
        rngTarget.Calculate
End Sub
```